# Build the sencha touch 2 app for production

Tags: sencha-touch-2

When I am trying to build my sencha touch 2 app for production using the command "sencha app build production", I am getting an error as shown in below image. I am not getting the reason for the error.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are using a [reserved Javascript keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) or perhaps left a `debugger;` somewhere in your code.

Comment: Thank you very much rdougan. I was stuck here for many days. There were debuggers; left in my app.

Comment: I had this problem too and it was the reserved word "long" being used in the code to represent "longitude". Took me several times looking at the one line of code I did this in to figure it out.